# XPUB XSUB identifying where subscriptions are coming from in zeromq

Tags: sockets, zeromq, messaging, publish-subscribe

Anyone have experience with XPUB and XSUB on ZeroMQ.  What I want to do control which topics a client can subscribe to on the server. I was thinking of using the XPUB/XSUB proxy and then forwarding only entitled subscription calls to the main publisher.  In doing this I am having a hard time finding where the subscription is coming from.  Does anyone know the ZMQ apis that will let me find out who is making the subscription?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can identify (by IP) subscription.
This only works for `tcp://` protocol.

```cpp
    struct Properties
    {
        std::optional<std::string> identity;
        std::optional<std::string> peerAddress;
    };

    Properties properties;
    zmq::message_t message; // the one you receive in xpub

    //message.gets - may throw...
    const char* identity = zmq_msg_gets(message.handle(), "Identity");
    if(identity != nullptr)
    {
        properties.identity.emplace(identity);
    }
    const char* addressRaw = zmq_msg_gets(message.handle(), "Peer-Address");
    if(addressRaw != nullptr)
    {
        properties.peerAddress.emplace(addressRaw);
    }
```

Checkout: http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-msg-gets

Other way could be just using REQ-REP to introduce yourself and then return valid topic list. But I would say you need rethink your problem and do it other way.